# How to generate a Round-Robin tournament?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code to generate a tournament with all vs all (Round-Robin) format, the number of teams to participate is entered and then the names of the teams are entered, continuing I have the function generarCompeticionRoundRobin where I generate a fixture with the previously entered teams . A number of rounds and a number of matches per round are generated. This part generates well but the problem is that it pits a team against itself which shouldn't happen. How could I fix this. Here is my code:

```js
import { useState } from "react";

function GenerarFixtureRoundRobin() {
  const [numeroDeEquipos, setNumeroDeEquipos] = useState(0);
  const [nombresEquipos, setNombresEquipos] = useState([]);

  const handleNumTeamsChange = (e) => {
    const contadorDeEquipos = parseInt(e.target.value);
    setNumeroDeEquipos(contadorDeEquipos);
    setNombresEquipos(Array(contadorDeEquipos).fill(""));
  };

  const handleTeamNameChange = (e, index) => {
    const nuevoNombre = e.target.value;
    setNombresEquipos((nombrePrevio) => {
      const actualizaNombre = [...nombrePrevio];
      actualizaNombre[index] = nuevoNombre;
      return actualizaNombre;
    });
  };

  const generarCompeticionRoundRobin = () => {
    if (numeroDeEquipos < 2) {
      console.log("Debe haber al menos 2 equipos para generar el fixture");
      return;
    }

    if (nombresEquipos.some((nombre) => nombre.trim() === "")) {
      console.log("Por favor, ingresa el nombre de todos los equipos.");
      return;
    }

    const numRondas = numeroDeEquipos - 1;
    const numEnfrentamientosPorRonda = numeroDeEquipos / 2;
    const numPartidosTotales = numRondas * numEnfrentamientosPorRonda;

    console.log("Fixture generado:");
    for (let ronda = 0; ronda < numRondas; ronda++) {
      console.log(`Ronda ${ronda + 1}`);
      for (
        let enfrentamiento = 0;
        enfrentamiento < numEnfrentamientosPorRonda;
        enfrentamiento++
      ) {
        const equipoLocal =
          nombresEquipos[(ronda + enfrentamiento) % (numeroDeEquipos - 1)];
        const equipoVisitante =
          nombresEquipos[
            (numeroDeEquipos - 1 - enfrentamiento + ronda) %
              (numeroDeEquipos - 1)
          ];
        console.log(`${equipoLocal} vs ${equipoVisitante}`);
      }
    }

    console.log(`Cantidad de rondas: ${numRondas}`);
    console.log(
      `Cantidad de enfrentamientos por ronda: ${numEnfrentamientosPorRonda}`
    );
    console.log(`Cantidad de partidos totales: ${numPartidosTotales}`);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Generador de Torneo</h2>
      <label>
        Número de equipos:
        <input
          type="number"
          value={numeroDeEquipos}
          onChange={handleNumTeamsChange}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      {nombresEquipos.map((name, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <label>
            Equipo {index + 1}:
            <input
              type="text"
              value={name}
              onChange={(e) => handleTeamNameChange(e, index)}
            />
          </label>
        </div>
      ))}
      <br />
      <button onClick={generarCompeticionRoundRobin}>
        Generar partidos Round Robin
      </button>
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
  );
}

export default GenerarFixtureRoundRobin;
```

This is how the fixture currently displays:

Ronda 1

Real madrid vs Real madrid

Barcelona vs Arsenal

Ronda 2

Barcelona vs Barcelona

Arsenal vs Real madrid

Ronda 3

Arsenal vs Arsenal

Real madrid vs Barcelona